# Pandas:How to fill in value from the same column but different row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-science

I have a requirement to fill out a column with values from same column but from different rows.

Example: Below is the data structure.

```
    fname   lname
0    bob    andy
1  manny  dorson
2    bob     NaN
```

Now for all "**lname**" values which are NaN, I want to fill those with "**lname**" values from the rows which share the common "**fname**"

So 3rd row which does not have "**lname**" I want to pick the "**lname**" from 1st row since "**fname**" for both the rows are same.
The result which I expect :

```
    fname   lname
0    bob    andy
1  manny  dorson
2    bob     andy
```

This is just a simple minified example.
And let's say, if there are multiple rows with matching first name, we can pick up the first one.
I tried a lot of things but not getting it to work.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupby` and `ffill`:

```
#To fill the NaN's with last value of group
df['lname'] = df.groupby('fname', as_index=False)['lname'].ffill()
```

---

```
#To fill the NaN's with first value of group
df['lname'] = (df['lname'].fillna(df.groupby('fname')['lname']
                                    .transform('first')))
```

Comment: Thanks @sandeep. First solution works(it's filling up with the last matched value though not first) . Second solution throws "TypeError: Transform function invalid for data types"

Comment: @ShadabAnsari Now, first solution fills with last value, second solution fills with first value. Check the updated code. Also upvote if it solves your problem.